# List Comprehensions with a condition on an array?

Tags: haskell, tuples, conditional-statements, list-comprehension

I have an array that contains tuples that look like this: `[((Int, Int), Int)]`. I am trying to create a new array with list comprehensions that says to only add all 3 Ints if the 3rd Int == a certain number. I have it written as

```
newArray = [((x,y),z) | ((x,y),z)<-oldArray, (snd oldArray) == 5]
```

However, when I try to run the code that contains this, it says "couldn't match expected type" and point the error at my conditional. `"Couldn't match expected type '(a0, Int)' with actual type '[((Int, Int), Int)]'"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`oldArray` is a list, always and forever, even inside the comprehension, so `snd` can't be applied to it. Use `z == 5` instead.